# Custom snap physics, which works in CustomScrollView, does not work in NestedScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview

I made a customized navigation bar that simulates iOS's navigation bar. I use nested_scroll_view_plus for stretching support and snap_scroll_physics package for snapping.

You can access the sample repo at the address below.
https://github.com/fikretsengul/nsw_plus_bug

My question is, as you can see in the video, when I scroll, if the scroll ends within the range I specified for the snap, the snap does not happen. This only applies when I use nested scroll view. If I use a custom scroll view, the same situation does not occur and it works without any problems.

https://github.com/idootop/nested_scroll_view_plus/assets/22684086/c213b522-d9a4-41b7-a733-cd4e0f3517c7

I think it is related to the synchronization between two (nested and custom) scroll controllers. I have to use nested scroll view because there are situations where I will use paginated list, so I can't just use custom scroll view. Is there any possible or hacky solution you can suggest to fix this?

(As a note, I would like to point out that the situation has nothing to do with nested_scroll_view_plus and easy_refresh. This is the case even if I don't use it.)